# Overflow hidden not working in FF & IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, overflow, hidden

I have overflow on the x-axis that I'm trying to hide in a container of `display:table`. The overflow is hidden in Chrome and Safari. As the title suggests, however, this is not happening in FF & IE 11.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6wLnsas/1/

I have tried both `overflow: hidden` and `overflow-x: hidden`, but the issues still persists in the identified browsers.

Comment: It works if you change `.fs-container` to `display: block`. Why does it need to be a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the overflow properties do not work on tables. Instead, try putting your table( or div with `display: table`) in another div.

Something like

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='my-table-div'>
    Random content
    </div>
</div>
```

Then put the overflow property on the container.